# Why mutating function next does not change the struct (conforming to Sequence and IteratorProtocol) after the iteration?

Tags: swift, sequence, mutating-function, iterator-protocol

I write a stack struct, and make it conforming to `IteratorProtocol` and `Sequence` protocol. The `next` function is mutating.  So I suppose the iteration of the stack will mutate the struct.

```
import Foundation


struct Stack<Element> {
    var store:[Element] = []

    mutating func push(_ element:Element) {
        store.append(element)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        return store.popLast()
    }
}


extension Stack: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        return pop()
    }

}

var stack = Stack<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)


for s in stack {
    print(s)
}

print(stack)
```

Here is the console output:
[image]

I don't understand why the stack is unchanged. I suppose it become empty after the mutating `next()` calls.

Comment: You never call `next()`. If you would, the output would become `2\n1\nStack<Int>(store:[1,2])`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder this is a horribly wrong suggestion

Comment: @user3581248 Calling a function you have defined is not a "horribly wrong suggestion". In fact, the accepted answer does this. Of course, changing it to a class is far more convenient, but mine is not "horribly wrong". I only wanted to suggest that `next()` does not get called.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder it gets called when you're iterating over the stack. That's the whole point of implementing the `IteratorProtocol`. The accepted answer's point is in its first sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for ... in`-Loop works on a copy of stack and never changes the stack itself. If you were to call `next()` yourself, the `pop()` would modify the stack as you can see here:

```
import Foundation

struct Stack<Element> {
    var store: [Element] = []

    mutating func push(_ element:Element) {
        store.append(element)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        return store.popLast()
    }
}


extension Stack: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        return pop()
    }
}

var stack = Stack<Int>()
stack.push(1)
stack.push(2)
stack.push(3)

for s in stack {
    print(s)
}

stack.next()

print(stack.store)
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
[1, 2]
```

However as @user3581248 pointed out in the comments, making Stack a class instead of a struct (and removing `mutating` from its functions) gives you the desired behavior.

Comment: Correct answer, but you could also add that changing the `Stack` type to a class would give the expected behaviour

Comment: changing struct to class tells everything. Thank you @user3581248

Comment: @user3581248 that's right, I added your remark to the answer for better visibility.